# SQL Audit and AlwaysOn Replicas

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

We would like to enable SQL Audit on a SQL Server 2014 database. This database is replicated to a read replica via AlwaysOn. We don't need, or want, the replica audited. If we enable audit on the main database, will it automatically get replicated to our replica? If so, is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference: [SQL Server Audit (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine)

> If we enable audit on the main database, will it automatically get
>   replicated to our replica?

No it will not automatically get replicated.

The Database Audit Specification object also belongs to a SQL Server audit.

The Server Audit Specification object belongs to an audit. You can create one server audit specification per audit, because both are created at the SQL Server instance scope.

Answer (score -1):

The Database Audit Specification object belongs to Database Level so it will be replicated to secondary.

Comment: You need to provide a reference, please.